# data.iterrows() + plt.imread() alternative, really exhausting

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, data

Currently, I'm loading my images for the training model with TensorFlow, like this:

```
for index, datum in data.iterrows():
  sat_name = directory_path+datum['sat_image_path']
  sat_img = plt.imread(sat_name)
  sat = cv.resize(sat_img,(SIZE,SIZE))
  tf_data['sat'].append(sat)
  print("Progress: ",(100*index)/data.size,"%")
  clear_output(wait=True)
```

I know this is not the best way to do it. But this is what I got. This `data` is `DataFrame`, swhich holds all the image-ids and their relative paths.

And this seems, pretty slow, it takes like 50 minutes in Colab, to load 12k images.

And when feeding to my model, I do something like this:

```
unet.fit(
      np.array(tf_data['sat']), 
      ...
```

Can anyone suggest to me a better way to do it, more faster and elegant and surely updated way?

Comment: Instead of loading all images into memory before fitting your model, you could write a custom data generator that loads the images as they are needed in the training process. In addition, you could try to load images using `cv2.imread` instead of `plt.imread` which may be a bit faster.

Comment: @Oxbowerce that made it faster, I guess you should post it as an answer... Dramatically reduced time to one-fourth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading all images into memory before fitting your model, you could write a custom data generator that loads the images as they are needed in the training process. In addition, you could try to load images using `cv2.imread` instead of `plt.imread` which may be a bit faster.